# Configure sendmail to send emails as 'example.com', but relay actual emails to 'example.com' to another server

Tags: sendmail

A cloud-based server set-up by a 3rd party is using sendmail to do email sending.

Now, the sendmail has been configured so that emails from `www-data@localhost` [1] is sent as `www-data@example.com`. The emails mostly are sent to the 3rd party email, for example `someone@example2.net` (notice different target domain).

However, now we need to also send email to `admins@example.com`. Attempting to do that, however, results in `550 5.1.1 <admins@example.com>... User unknown`.

I'm severely in the blank for configuring sendmail.

Can anyone provide some pointers on how to do this properly?

[1] That is the `ServerAdmin` name as defined in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

---

@MadHatter asked:

> "the sendmail has been configured so that emails from www-data@localhost is sent as www-data@example.com". How, exactly?

I *think* through the following lines in `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`:

```
dnl # Replace sender's domain
MASQUERADE_AS(`example.com')dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`example.com')dnl
```

(Again, I'm not the one making the sendmail.mc file; if there's a certain line to look for, I'd be happy to post it here).

---

Here are additional info:

```
root@webserver:/etc/mail# grep '^Fw' sendmail.cf
Fw/etc/mail/local-host-names %[^\#]
root@webserver:/etc/mail# cat local-host-names
localhost
webserver
```

Comment: You say that "*the sendmail has been configured so that emails from www-data@localhost is sent as www-data@example.com*".  How, exactly?

Comment: That should be fine, thanks.  It doesn't explain why mail for `example.com` is being delivered locally.  Could you edit into your question that result of `grep '^Fw' /etc/mail/sendmail.cf`, and the contents of the file that then appears?

Comment: Thank you, that's great.  Also strange; why does this mail server think that it's authoritative for `example.com`?  Could you add the results of `hostname` and `echo ""|sendmail -bt -d0,11`?

Answer (score 0):

Is `example.com` listed on list of local email domains?
To get list of local email domains execute as root the command below:

```
echo '$=w' | sendmail -Am -bt
```

Sendmail by default adds autodetected local email domains to domains listed in `/etc/mail/local-host-names` . It can be turned off using [confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/tweaking_config.html#confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES) in sendmail.mc

```
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES',`True')
```

sendmail.mc must be recompiled into sendmail.cf, sendmail daemon must be restarted or HUPed to see new sendmail.cf.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for attempting to answer my question!

Over the weekend, the guy originally setting up the server finally modified `sendmail.mc` with the following (I just received his email this morning):

- Delete the following line:

> ```
> define(`confDOMAIN_NAME', `example.com')dnl
> ```

- Add one line after the previously posted 4 lines:

> ```
> MASQUERADE_AS(`example.com')dnl
> FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
> FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
> MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`example.com')dnl
> define(`MAIL_HUB', `mailgw.example.com.')dnl
> ```

Now emails to `@example.com` gets properly routed to the actual mailserver serving `@example.com`.

Thanks for the assistance, guys!